# how to join multiple models in on ecto query Ecto

Tags: postgresql, ecto

I have 3 models as `Vendor`, `VendorModel` and `Camera`. I am doing this query to get `VendorModels`.

```
query = from vm in VendorModel,
          join: v in Vendor, on: vm.vendor_id == v.id,
          where: like(fragment("lower(?)", vm.name), ^("%#{search}%")),
          where: like(fragment("lower(?)", v.name), ^("%#{search}%"))
models = query |> add_sorting(column, order) |> preload(:vendor) |> Evercam.Repo.all()
```

I am appending `order_by` through a method add_sorting which only adds up the `order_by` such as

```
  defp add_sorting(query, "exid", order) do
    from [vm, _v] in query,
      order_by: [{^sort_order(order), vm.exid}]
  end
```

After getting all models I am doing `Enum.reduce`to format an object on of all models. On each `VendorModel` there is an association with `Camera`, And I am getting a count for each model referenced in cameras such as

```
  Enum.reduce(display_start..index_end, [], fn i, acc ->
    model = Enum.at(models, i)
    vm = %{
      vendor_exid: model.vendor.exid,
      exid: model.exid,
      camera_count: Camera |> where(model_id: ^model.id) |> Evercam.Repo.all() |> Enum.count(),
    }
    acc ++ [vm]
  end)
```

this always ran another query for each model to get the count of cameras, Is there any possibility to add this count query to above the first query.  And it also supports order by?

I have read about subquery and group_by but I couldn't make it work

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

in `PostgreSQL` query is like this

```
SELECT vendor_models.id, vendor_models.name, v.name, count(cameras.id) as count 
  FROM vendor_models
  INNER JOIN vendors as v ON vendor_models.vendor_id = v.id 
  INNER JOIN cameras ON vendor_models.id = cameras.model_id
  WHERE lower(vendor_models.name) like lower('%ax%') OR lower(v.name) like lower('%ax%')
  GROUP BY vendor_models.id, vendor_models.name, v.name
  ORDER BY v.name asc
```

But I have no idea how it will be in ecto.

UPDATE:
Final query is like this

```
SELECT vm.*, v.name as vname, count(cameras.id) as count 
  FROM vendor_models as vm
  INNER JOIN vendors as v ON vm.vendor_id = v.id 
  INNER JOIN cameras ON vm.id = cameras.model_id
  WHERE lower(vm.name) like lower('%ax%') OR lower(v.name) like lower('%ax%')
  GROUP BY vm.id, v.name
  ORDER BY v.name asc
```

Can you help me to convert it into Ecto one?